# ¿Por que me da Assertion Error?

Tags: java, compilador, enum

Me ha surgido un error al compilar una aplicacion que permite jugar al juego de Bacará, con una clase `TestManoDeBacara`. Tengo la clase `Carta`, con su valor y su palo de tipo `Enum`:

```
    public enum PaloBarajaFrancesa {
    TREBOLES, DIAMANTES, CORAZONES, PICAS;
}

    public enum ValorBarajaFrancesa {
    AS, DOS, TRES, CUATRO, CINCO, SEIS, SIETE, OCHO, NUEVE, DIEZ, JOTA, REINA, REY;
}
```

Clase Carta:

```
    public class Carta {
    public final ValorBarajaFrancesa valor;
    public final PaloBarajaFrancesa palo;

    public Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa valor,PaloBarajaFrancesa palo) {
        this.valor=valor;
        this.palo=palo;
    }

}
```

Mano de Bacara: el valor de una mano de Bacará se calcula sumando el valor de las cartas de la mano, pero sabiendo que las cartas que sean AS,DOS,TRES,CUATRO,CINCO,SEIS,SIETE,OCHO,NUEVE, valen 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 respectivamente, y DIEZ,JOTA,REINA,REY valen 0. A esa suma hay que hacerle la division modular entre 10. En el bacara gana la mano cuya puntuacion se acerque más al 9, que es el máximo de puntuacion.

```
    public class ManoDeBacara {
    private Carta[] cartas;
    private int indice;
    private static final int NUMERODECARTAS=3;

    // Constructor
    public ManoDeBacara(){
    cartas=new Carta[NUMERODECARTAS];
    indice=0;
    }

    //Método obtenerValor
     //Recorre el array de resultados calcula el ordinal y devuelve el resultado final
    private int obtenerValor(Carta[] cartas){
        int valor=0;
    int valorCarta;
    for(indice=0; indice<NUMERODECARTAS;indice++) {
        if(cartas[indice]!=null) {
            if((cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("DIEZ"))||(cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("JOTA"))||(cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("REY"))||(cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("REINA")))
            {
                valorCarta=0;
        }else {
            valorCarta=cartas[indice].valor.ordinal()+1;                
        }
            valor+=valorCarta;
            valor%=10;
        }
    }
    return valor; 
    }


    /**
     * Método añadirCarta
     * Añade una carta a la mano de Bacará.
     * @param carta - Carta que se añade a la mano de Bacará
     * @return true si se pudo añadir la carta a la mano.
     * false si no se pudo añadir la carta por no admitir más cartas la mano.
     */
    public boolean añadirCarta(Carta carta){
        boolean cartaAñadida = false;
        if(indice<cartas.length){
            cartas[indice]=carta;
                indice++;
                cartaAñadida=true;
        }
            return cartaAñadida;

    }
    /**
     * Método ganaA
     * Indica si la mano utilizada para invocar al método es ganadora frente a la mano que se recibe como argumento.
     * Para saber cómo se puntúa una mano de Bacará se recomienda consultar la documentacion del reglamento del Bacará.
     * @param mano - Mano a comparar con la mano utilizada para invocar al método.
     * @return true si la mano utilizada para invocar al método es ganadora frente a la mano que se recibe como argumento.
     */
    public boolean ganaA(ManoDeBacara mano){
        boolean manoEsGanadora=false;
    manojugador=new ManoDeBacara();
    int valorbanca=mano.obtenerValor(cartas);
    int valorjugador=manojugador.obtenerValor(cartas);
    if((valorjugador > valorbanca)) 
        manoEsGanadora=true;

    return manoEsGanadora;
    }
    /**
     * Método obtenerMano
     * Devuelve una representación textual de la mano en forma de una secuencia de cartas, donde cada carta se representa a su vez con su valor y palo.
     * Por ejemplo, si la mano tiene dos cartas (tres de picas y rey de diamantes) entonces su representación textual será "[TRES/PICAS, REY/DIAMANTES]".
     * @return Representación textual de la mano.
     */
    public String obtenerMano(){
        String cadena="[";

    for(int i=0; i<NUMERODECARTAS;i++){
        if(cartas[i]!=null)
            cadena=cadena.concat(cartas[i].valor.name()+"/"+cartas[i].palo.name()+"],");
    }
    //for, hay que recorrer el array para los valores que tengamos y separarlos por comas

    return cadena;
    }


}
```

Le estoy pasando `TestManoDeBacara`, que es necesario que lo pase sin errores, pero sin embargo me da `AssertionError`:

```
public class TestManoDeBacara {

private static final Carta AS = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.AS, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta DOS = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.DOS, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta TRES = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.TRES, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta CUATRO = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.CUATRO, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta CINCO = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.CINCO, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta SEIS = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.SEIS, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta SIETE = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.SIETE, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta OCHO = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.OCHO, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta NUEVE = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.NUEVE, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta DIEZ = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.DIEZ, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta JOTA = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.JOTA, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta REINA = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.REINA, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Carta REY = new Carta(ValorBarajaFrancesa.REY, PaloBarajaFrancesa.DIAMANTES);
private static final Boolean VERDADERO = Boolean.valueOf(true);
private static final Boolean FALSO = Boolean.valueOf(false);

static final Object[][] jugadasYResultados = {
//          mano1                           mano2                           mano2 es mano ganadora frente a mano1
        { AS,       REY,        null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },
        { REY,      AS,     null,       REY     , AS        , null,     FALSO },

        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , AS        , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      REY,        null,       AS      , REY       , null,     VERDADERO },

        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , AS        , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { REY,      AS,         null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },

        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , AS        , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       AS,         null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },

        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , AS        , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { AS,       DOS,        null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },

        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , AS        , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      DOS,        null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },

        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , AS        , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { DOS,      TRES,       null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },

        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , AS        , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     TRES,       null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },

        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , AS        , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     VERDADERO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     VERDADERO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { TRES,     CUATRO,     null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },

        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , AS        , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , DOS       , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , TRES      , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , CUATRO    , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , CINCO     , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , SEIS      , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , SIETE     , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , OCHO      , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , NUEVE     , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , DIEZ      , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , JOTA      , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , REINA     , null,     FALSO },
        { CUATRO,   CINCO,      null,       AS      , REY       , null,     FALSO },
        null
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int idxJugada;
    idxJugada = 0;
    final ManoDeBacara manoDeBacara = new ManoDeBacara();
    for(java.lang.reflect.Field f:manoDeBacara.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
        EVALUAR ( java.lang.reflect.Modifier.isPrivate(f.getModifiers()), "Error: puedo acceder al atributo " + f.getName() + " de la mano de Bacara" );

    while(jugadasYResultados[idxJugada] != null)
        extraerYProbarDatos(jugadasYResultados[idxJugada++]);
    System.out.println("Test terminado sin errores.");
}

private static void extraerYProbarDatos(Object[] elementos) {
    int idxElemento;
    idxElemento = 0;
    ManoDeBacara a;
    a = new ManoDeBacara();
    while(elementos[idxElemento] != null)
        a.añadirCarta((Carta)elementos[idxElemento++]);
    ManoDeBacara b;
    b = new ManoDeBacara();
    idxElemento++;
    while(elementos[idxElemento] != null)
        b.añadirCarta((Carta)elementos[idxElemento++]);
    boolean esManoGanadora = (Boolean)elementos[++idxElemento];
    testJugada(a, b, esManoGanadora);
}

private static void testJugada(ManoDeBacara a, ManoDeBacara b, boolean esManoGanadora) {
    EVALUAR(b.ganaA(a) == esManoGanadora, "ERROR: [" + (esManoGanadora ? b.obtenerMano() : a.obtenerMano()) + "] debe ser mano ganadora frente a [" + (esManoGanadora ? a.obtenerMano() : b.obtenerMano()) + "]");
}

private static void EVALUAR(boolean predicado, String mensajeDeError) {
    if(!predicado) throw new AssertionError(mensajeDeError);
}
```

}

Y el error en pantalla:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: ERROR: [[AS/DIAMANTES],AS/DIAMANTES],] debe ser mano ganadora frente a [[REY/DIAMANTES],REY/DIAMANTES],]
    at TestManoDeBacara.EVALUAR(TestManoDeBacara.java:196)
    at TestManoDeBacara.testJugada(TestManoDeBacara.java:192)
    at TestManoDeBacara.extraerYProbarDatos(TestManoDeBacara.java:188)
    at TestManoDeBacara.main(TestManoDeBacara.java:171)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error sale por un test en la clase `TestManoDeBacara`. En concreto el test es `TestManoDeBacara#testJugada`, que comprueba que el método `#ganaA` funcione correctamente.

He seguido el método `ganaA` y me he dado cuenta de que estás creando una nueva mano cada vez que llamas al método. **Es un error, porque de esa manera no estás comparando una mano ajena con la mano sobre la que estás llamando el método**.

Dicho de otro modo: imagina que tú tienes una mano y quieres comprobarla contra la de la banca. Tal como lo tienes hecho, con el método `ganaA` siendo perteneciente a una instancia de `ManoDeBacara` *(tu mano)*, estás pidiendo a tu mano que compruebe su valor contra la de la banca. Hasta ahí bien. **El problema es que al crear una nueva mano y no usar la tuya (usando `this`), de repente no estás comprobando tu mano contra la banca sino una nueva mano *vacía* contra la banca**.

De ahí he seguido mirando y me he encontrado otro error, que te describo brevemente: para calcular el valor de una mano, tienes que pasarle un array de cartas, y el array de cartas es privado, lo mismo que el método. **¿Cómo esperas sacar el valor de las cartas de otra mano, si no sabes qué cartas tiene esa mano?** Yo cambiaría la firma del método para que no necesite el array de cartas, y tome el que ya tienes en la propia clase.

Así que quedaría así:

```
public int obtenerValor(){  // ahora es publico para poder acceder a el
    int valor=0;            // y no necesita un array de cartas para calcularlo, usa el de la mano
    int valorCarta;
    for(indice=0; indice<NUMERODECARTAS;indice++) {
        if(cartas[indice]!=null) {
            if((cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("DIEZ"))||(cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("JOTA"))||(cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("REY"))||(cartas[indice].valor.name().equals("REINA")))
            {
                valorCarta=0;
            }else {
                valorCarta=cartas[indice].valor.ordinal()+1;
            }
            valor+=valorCarta;
            valor%=10;
        }
    }
    return valor;
}

public boolean ganaA(Mano mano) {
    int valorJugador = obtenerValor();      // el valor de ESTA mano
    int valorBanca = mano.obtenerValor();   // el valor de la otra mano

    return valorJugador > valorBanca;
}
```